# can two IF condition work simultaneously

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a js program to check a condition using two IF conditions simultaneously. Why doesnt it work? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rosalind_sandya/uhuH9/1/)

```
    function displayIcon() {
    var a = 1;
    var i = 2;
    if (a == 1) {

        $('.clist').show();
        $('.vPrint').show();
        $('.vFilter').show();
        $('.vSaveAs').show();
        $('.vShare').show();
    } else if (a === 0) {

        $('.vPrint').show();
        $('.vFilter').show();
    }

    if (i == 2) {
        $('.alertInfo').show();
    } else if (i == 4) {
        $('.alertInfo').hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be adding a jquery library to the fiddle.. 

Also change the "===" to "=="

This should work..

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `===`...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript bit of further reading...

Answer (score 3):

It works just fine for me. All you have to do to make it work in jsFiddle is:

- Enable the jQuery plugin, so that `$` is defined; and
- Change the function wrapping to "no wrap", otherwise the `displayIcon` function is only defined within the wrapper and cannot be accessed by the button.

Answer (score 1):

Your fiddle had 2 issues:

- You're calling jQuery functions without loading jQuery
- Your `displayIcon` function wasn't defined in the same scope that you were trying to call it from

[Here's an updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/uhuH9/5/) that should work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable jQuery.

You could also consider using a switch:

```
switch(a) {
    case 1: 
        $('.clist').show();
        $('.vPrint').show();
        $('.vFilter').show();
        $('.vSaveAs').show();
        $('.vShare').show();
        break;
    case 0:
        $('.vPrint').show();
        $('.vFilter').show();
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/RWXYh/1/) is the working fiddle for you

```
var s = document.getElementById("myctrl");
s.onclick = function displayIcon() {
```

Answer (score 0):

In fiddle change 'onLoad' option into No wrap in body.
Then add jquery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I've got the answer to the question I asked. Two IF conditions can work together. The following code provides the needful.

```
int a=2, b=3;
if(a<b)
{
alert("B is bigger");
}
if(b<a)
{
alert("A is bigger");
}
```